# Category attribute database design

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, e-commerce

I have 5 tables for e-commerce project:

```
 Items, category, category_parent, filters, filter_name
```

There are parent/child categories.

There can be one category has multiple child category and also one category can has multiple parent categories.

Like this:

Parent C has D and E child categories.

But C category is child of A and B.

All items have attributes.

For example PC category has

```
Ram(1GB, 2GB, 4GB), 
Screen-size(13, 15, 17), 
SSD(250gb, 500gb, 1tb) etc. attributes.
```

These attributes must be belong Computers and Electronics parent category.

But not child categories of PC.

How can I create attributes db design?

Here is my database: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/25098256/

Comment: Please do not use images and/or links for anything you can write in text. Use code block format for code (click on "{}").